# Return value from anonymous function to parent function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have a setup like this:

```
function test(){
    function(){
        return "testing!";
    };
    return;
}

echo test();
```

And I'm trying to get the `test()` function to return "testing" *(in this example)* but that doesn't work. What would you advice?

**Why are you using an anonymouse function?** 
I have to use an anonymous function for this because I'm using the HttpClient of ReactPHP, here's a basic example of how that works:

```
$request = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/reactphp/react/commits');
$request->on('response', function ($response) {
    $buffer = '';

    $response->on('data', function ($data) use (&$buffer) {
        $buffer .= $data;
        echo ".";
    });

    $response->on('end', function () use (&$buffer) {
        $decoded = json_decode($buffer, true);
        $latest = $decoded[0]['commit'];
        $author = $latest['author']['name'];
        $date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($latest['author']['date']));

        echo "\n";
        echo "Latest commit on react was done by {$author} on {$date}\n";
        echo "{$latest['message']}\n";
    });
});
$request->on('end', function ($error, $response) {
    echo $error;
});
$request->end();
```

In the example above they echo the content of the page, but I'd like to return it instead, any help would be **much** appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `$request` really work asynchronous? Might there be a situation, when calling script ends, before request is done?

Comment: How do you run / execute `$request` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about **call_user_func**?

```
function test(){
    return call_user_func(function(){
        return "testing!";
    });
}

echo test();
```

According to the docs:

> Return Values
>
> Returns the return value of the callback, or FALSE on error.

#### Further Reading

[call_user_func documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

#### Edit:

I suggest you look into using a different library for your http requests that is not asynchronous.

Alternatively you can do some busy waiting while you wait for the request to complete.  To do this have a variable in the outermost scope set to `null`.  Set this variable to the request's result once you get it.  After you've set up all the callbacks keep checking the variable for something other than `null` ([sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) in between checks).  Also set a callback on error to set this variable to something like `false` so that the program can get out of the loop if it fails.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because reactPHP will call the function when the response is complete, I can't immediately call it.

Comment: @user2019515 waht do you mean? Why do you need **nested** anonymous function then?

Comment: @CORRUPT Please see the example. That's how reactPHP works, you need to provide a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's impossible. You have to return the value to the outer function, which must then return its own value:

```
function test(){
    $fn = function(){
        return "testing!";
    };

    return $fn();
}
```

Your *inner* function doesn't get to return out of the *outer* function.

Comment: Right, I could add a return in the outer function no problemo but I can't assign the function to a variable.

Comment: Well, you need to immediately invoke the function and return its value then.

Comment: I can't invoke it right away, reactPHP calls the function when all the data is received.

Comment: Then re-read my answer: You can't, that's impossible. Especially if the inner function is being called asynchronously; the outer function will have already returned before the inner `return` is reached. It's now **double** impossible.